# Prove that a functional is $\alpha$ convex and continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

I have hard time trying to prove this functional is $\alpha$ convex and continuous

$$
J(v) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\lvert v'(x)\rvert dx - \int_{0}^{1}f(x)v(x)dx
$$

Where $v\in H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$ and $f \in L^2(0,1)$.

For the continuity I have tried the following. Take $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$.

$$
\lvert J(v_1) - J(v_2) \rvert \leq \frac{1}{2}\left\lvert \int_{0}^{1}\lvert v_1^{'}(x)\rvert -\lvert v_2^{'}(x)\rvert dx\right\rvert + \int_{0}^{1}\lvert f(x)(v_1(x) -v_2(x))\rvert dx \leq \frac{1}{2}\lVert v_1^{'}- v_2^{'}\rVert_{L^2} + \lVert f\rVert_{L^2}\lVert v_1 - v_2\rVert_{L^2}
$$

Using the norm on the space $H_{0}^{1}$ defined by $\lVert u\rVert_{H} = \lVert u\rVert_{L^2} + \lVert u’\rVert_{L^2}$. Now let us consider $\varepsilon>0$, we take $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}}$ and it follows that

$$
\lvert J(v_1) - J(v_2) \rvert \leq \varepsilon\left(1+\frac{1}{2\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}}\right)
$$

I would like to know if this is correct and have your hints on this problem please or what can be done in a better way !

Thank you a lot !

Sorry for the latex code I do not see where is the problem for the compilation

Comment: You can use $\delta' = \delta (1 + (2\|f\|)^{-1})^{-1}$ instead

Comment: @night_owl Thank you for the comment ! I have been a little lazy in the optimal delta since the term $\left(1+\frac{1}{2\lVert f\rVert_{L^2}}\right)$  is independent of $v_1$ and $v_2$. But I will look to your delta and see what happens with !